# MVC: Add output cache for all actions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

One of my MVC project is close to the end. We are trying to optimize the project with Output Cache.

However, We found there are so many Controllers with even more Actions. We do not think to add the Output Cache attribute to each Action is a good idea.

Is there any solution that I could add Output Cache to each Action for one time?

Comment: use a 'BaseController' and inherit all controllers from the BaseController. You can use OutputCache for the BaseController which will apply to all child controllers. In that way you can avoid specifying for each Action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it to Global Filters.

```
filters.Add(new OutputCacheAttribute 
 { 
    NoStore = true, 
    Duration = 0,
    VaryByParam = "*"
 });
```

You can do this in `FilterConfig.cs` file in `App_Start` folder.

Comment: You are all the heros

Answer (score 0):

Use global filters  in FilterConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
        {

                OutputCacheAttribute cache = new OutputCacheAttribute();
                  //set other properties
                filters.Add(cache);
}
```